# Simple, encapsulated C++ logger that can deal with fork/exec situations

Tags: c++, beginner, locking, logging, child-process

Motivation:  for whatever reason, some of the available 3rd party logging libraries don't really deal with programs that get fork'ed/exectuted well.  For instance, `boost::log` creates some static state that can cause deadlocks if the program using it gets forked.

This class attempts to be a simple logger for programs that get forked/exec'ed.

For locking, I chose to use a boost interprocess mutex rather than a file lock, because if a child process gets stuck with the lock taken out, restarting the parent process will destroy the current mutex and create a new one.

I'm looking for style, performance and viability feedback.  I've tested it and it seems to work well enough.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/permissions.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_sharable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>


static const char *kLoggerSegmentName = "MPLLoggerSeg";
static const char *kLoggerMutexName= "MPLLoggerIPCMutex";

enum LogLevel { MPLTRACE, MPLDEBUG, MPLINFO, MPLWARN, MPLERROR, MPLFATAL };


class MultiProcessLogger  {
private:
    LogLevel      fLoggingLevel;
    bool          fEnabled;
    bool          fParent;
    std::ofstream fLogFile;


    inline void writeToFile(std::string &msg) {
        using namespace boost::interprocess;
        managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, kLoggerSegmentName);
        interprocess_sharable_mutex *mutex = segment.find<interprocess_sharable_mutex>(kLoggerMutexName).first;
        scoped_lock<interprocess_sharable_mutex> lock(*mutex);
        fLogFile  << msg;
        //lock automatically unlocks when scope is left.
    }

    inline const char *getLevelString() {
        switch(fLoggingLevel) {
            case MPLTRACE:
                return "<trace>";
            case MPLDEBUG:
                return "<debug>";
            case MPLINFO:
                return "<info.>";
            case MPLWARN:
                return "<warn.>";
            case MPLERROR:
                return "<error>";
            case MPLFATAL:
                return "<fatal>";
            default:
                return "<     >";
        }
    }

    void destroySharedMemory() {
        using namespace boost::interprocess;
        try
        {
            shared_memory_object::remove(kLoggerSegmentName);
        } catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "Error:  unable to remove segment: " << kLoggerSegmentName << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //disable copy constructor.
    MultiProcessLogger(MultiProcessLogger &that);

public:

    MultiProcessLogger(bool enabled, const char* logDir, const char* fileName, LogLevel level) :
        fLoggingLevel(level), fEnabled(enabled), fParent(false) {
        if (!fEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        std::string logFilePath(logDir);
        logFilePath.append("/");
        logFilePath.append(fileName);
        fLogFile.open(logFilePath.c_str(), std::ios::app);
    }


    ~MultiProcessLogger() {
        if (!fEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        fLogFile.close();
        if (fParent) {
            destroySharedMemory();
        }
    }

    void initParentProcess() {
        using namespace boost::interprocess;
        fParent = true;
        destroySharedMemory();
        permissions perms;
        perms.set_unrestricted();
        managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, kLoggerSegmentName, 1024, 0, perms);
        interprocess_sharable_mutex *mutex= segment.construct<interprocess_sharable_mutex>(kLoggerMutexName)();
        if (!mutex) {
            std::cerr << "Error:  unable to create interprocess mutex for logger" << std::endl;
            abort();
        }
    }

    void initChildProcess() {
        fParent = false;
    }


    void log(LogLevel level, const char* msg, ...) {
        if (!fEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        if (fLoggingLevel > level) {
            return;
        }

        va_list args;
        va_start(args, msg);
        char msgBuf[512];
        vsnprintf(msgBuf, sizeof msgBuf, msg, args);
        va_end(args);
        std::string logMessage;

        //format:
        //time <level> proc:pid message


        boost::posix_time::ptime now  = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
        boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet();
        facet->format("%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Q");
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), facet));
        stream << now;

        logMessage.append(stream.str());
        logMessage.append(" ");
        logMessage.append(getLevelString());
        logMessage.append(" ");
        logMessage.append("process");
        logMessage.append(":");
        char pidStr[6];
        snprintf(pidStr, 6, "%05d", getpid());
        logMessage.append(pidStr);
        logMessage.append(" ");
        logMessage.append(msgBuf);
        logMessage.append("\n");
        writeToFile(logMessage);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
//in parent process
MultiProcessLogger logger(true, "/tmp", "myLog.log", MLPINFO);
logger.initParentProcess();
...
logger.log(MPLERROR, "hello %s", "world");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 512 is really a small fixed-size buffer for the formatted message (seriously)

  - Given all the other stuff the function has to do, I'd go with a dynamic buffer here as well. (Calling [vsnprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) with `0` as buffer size should tell you how much you need.
- the `log` function seems horribly inefficient: Creating the facet each time, multiple `append` without preallocation
- Just use a single `stringstream` for the whole `logMessage`